# How to make int value in android usb host vendor-id value

Tags: android, usb

I'm using USB host API for my android app. My code follows what is required in the developer [site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html#usage). Now I got issue on the `device_filter.xml`, android doesn't recognize the `vendor-id="03eb"` as `int`

It gives me this warning:

```
W/UsbSettingsManager( 1455): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "03eb"
W/UsbSettingsManager( 1455): at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
W/UsbSettingsManager( 1455): at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
```

This is true, but how do I make this into an `int` in `<usb-device vendor-id="03eb"`?

[image]

AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.usb.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</activity>
```

In the device_filter.xml

```
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="03eb" product-id="6201" />
</resources>
```

Comment: I have never seen alphabets like e and b in Integer. Integer can only have numbers

Comment: @Peshal These are hexadecimal (base 16) numbers. It's reasonable to assume that the `vendor-id` and `product-id` fields would accept hex since many queries of vendor id and product id [list the values in  hex](https://devicehunt.com/view/type/usb/vendor/18D1) - e.g. vendor ID for Google is `18D1` and Nexus One product ID is `4E11` As @sanmai says below, it looks like you just need to include the standard `0x` prefix to specify them in hex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vendor and Product ids must be integers, but you are passing hexadecimal values. You can simply convert hex to an integer representation. [See this link.](http://easycalculation.com/hex-converter.php) Here are the conversions:

03eb -> 1003

6201 -> 25089

Comment: Technically hexadecimal numbers are also **integers** but in base 16.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass hexadecimal numbers in an appropriate notation:

```xml
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="0x03eb" product-id="0x6201" />
</resources>
```